# "value partially assigned here after move" for a vector element

Tags: rust

I am very new to Rust, and I am still fighting with the basic concepts of borrowing and ownership.

I am trying to initialise a vector of struct's, but each element is created in several steps, so I was thinking of using a "current_element" variable which I can modify.  That would be something like this:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct A {
    value1: u8, 
    value2: u8,
}

fn main() {
    let v = create();
    println!("{:?}", v)
}

fn create() -> Vec<A> {
    let mut v: Vec<A> = Vec::new();
    // First step, set value1
    let mut current_element = A { value1: 1, value2: 0 };
    v.push(current_element);
    
    // second step, set value2
    current_element.value2 = 2; 

    v
}
```

I understand that is not possible like this, as I get a "value partially assigned here after move" error.

How could I get around that problem?  I just cannot find a way...

Comment: Assuming you can't do the direct solution (only inserting after fully constructed/modified), you might want to just keep the index and mutate it through the vector: `v[current_element_index].value2 = 2;` Though that's just a guess, its not clear why your vector creation has these steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all the initializing beforehand.

```rs
let mut current_element = A { value1: 1, value2: 0 };
current_element.value2 = 2; 
v.push(current_element);
```

Or you can get a reference to the element you just pushed and modify it through that.

```rs
let mut current_element = A { value1: 1, value2: 0 };
v.push(current_element);
    
let element = v.last_mut().unwrap();
element.value2 = 2;
```

Or you can remove it from the `Vec` while you modify it, and put it back.

```rs
let mut current_element = A { value1: 1, value2: 0 };
v.push(current_element);

let mut element = v.pop().unwrap();
element.value2 = 2; 
v.push(element);
```

The second one only works when you're dealing with one element. If you want to update an element somewhere in the middle of the `Vec`, you'll need to save its index and use that instead of `last_mut`. If you want to hold mutable references to multiple items, you can obtain them by destructuring, or with methods like [`split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.split_at_mut).